# Certificado SSL - Como configurar no Servidor

Tags: apache, servidor, ssl

Boa tarde

Estou tentando ativar o certificado de segurança em meu site.

Já coloquei o arquivos:

Já fiz todos os processos para gerar os arquivos de registro esta tudo ok.

Coloquei os registros dentro do meu servidor.

Agora não sei qual arquivo configurar para que o certificado seja reconhecido.

O meu site fica armazenado em um servidor apache.

Obrigado

Comment: Versão do webserver? Sistema operacional?

Comment: @ShutUpMagda Ubutu e não faço a menor ideia do que venha a ser WebServer

Comment: Não sabe o que é servidor WEB? Olha, assim fica difícil... Se sua dúvida não é especificada, e você precisa de tutorial, a internet está cheia deles. Tente esse aqui: [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04).